# Jetpack compose BottomNavigation - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached to lifecycleOwner

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

When I double click the same item or if I go to each composable screen very quickly i receive an error, How do I solve this problem? I tried changing few things but I just can't solve it and I can't find any resources to fix this problem.

Bottom Navigation implementation

```
@Composable
fun BottomNav(
    navController: NavController,
    bottomNavState: MutableState<Boolean>,
) {

    val navItems = listOf(
        Screen.HomeScreen,
        Screen.BookmarkScreen,
        Screen.MyRecipesScreen,
        Screen.FavouriteScreen
    )

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = bottomNavState.value,
        enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
        exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it }),
        content = {
            BottomNavigation(
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                elevation = 12.dp
            ) {

                val bottomNavBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentDestination = bottomNavBackStackEntry?.destination

                navItems.forEach { item ->

                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        icon = {
                            Icon(painter = painterResource(id = item.icon), contentDescription = "")
                        },
                        label = {
                            Text(text = item.title)
                        },
                        selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == item.route } == true,
                        onClick = {

                            navController.navigate(item.route) {


                                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true


                            }

                        },
                        selectedContentColor = Color.Black,
                        unselectedContentColor = Color.LightGray,
                        alwaysShowLabel = true,
                    )

                }

            }
        }
    )

}
```

Error Received

```
2022-03-05 11:50:10.183 8460-8460/com.im.cookgaloreapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.im.cookgaloreapp, PID: 8460
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached to lifecycleOwner
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.attachToLifecycle(SavedStateHandleController.java:38)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleAttacher.onRecreated(SavedStateHandleSupport.kt:139)
        at androidx.savedstate.Recreator.reflectiveNew(Recreator.java:90)
        at androidx.savedstate.Recreator.onStateChanged(Recreator.java:62)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:271)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:313)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:151)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.setCurrentState(LifecycleRegistry.java:121)
        at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.updateState(NavBackStackEntry.kt:188)
        at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.setMaxLifecycle(NavBackStackEntry.kt:154)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.updateBackStackLifecycle$navigation_runtime_release(NavController.kt:987)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.dispatchOnDestinationChanged(NavController.kt:892)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1726)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1658)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1980)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:1975)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1961)
        at com.im.cookgaloreapp.ui.components.BottomNavigationKt$BottomNav$3$1$1$2.invoke(BottomNavigation.kt:67)
        at com.im.cookgaloreapp.ui.components.BottomNavigationKt$BottomNav$3$1$1$2.invoke(BottomNavigation.kt:57)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:153)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke(Clickable.kt:142)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TapGestureDetectorKt$detectTapAndPress$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(TapGestureDetector.kt:223)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:178)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:328)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter$PointerEventHandlerCoroutine.offerPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:511)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.dispatchPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:406)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:419)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:310)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.NodeParent.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:179)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputEventProcessor.process-BIzXfog(PointerInputEventProcessor.kt:80)
2022-03-05 11:50:10.184 8460-8460/com.im.cookgaloreapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1205)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1155)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1095)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:488)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4125)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:446)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14568)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6016)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5310)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5485)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5542)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8031)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8203)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:220)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Make sure you're using latest dependencies, first of all compose navigation. If this doesn't help, such issues should be [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128), including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This issue seems to have finally been fixed in `2.5.0-alpha04`. Commenting for extra awareness.

Comment: Upgrading to `2.5.0-alpha04` did indeed fix this issue for me, but introduced a new issue; if I navigate quickly between tabs, I get the error:

`NoSuchElementException: List contains no element matching the predicate.`

Downgrading to `2.5.0-alpha02` fixes both issues for me, however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem using the latest compose navigation dependency `2.5.0-alpha03`.

I don't know why it's happening.

Philip Dukhov is right, you should report this issue.

Here is a dirty workaround :

```kotlin
try {
    // The navigation code that throw this exception
} catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
    if (e.message != "Already attached to lifecycleOwner") {
        throw e
    } else {
        // You can log the exception if you want
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like it is a bug indeed at 2.5.0-alpha03, I downgraded mine with 2.5.0-alpha02

Comment: Downgrading to `2.5.0-alpha02` did **not** work for me. I don't know if it was available at the time of your posting, but upgrading to `2.5.0-alpha04` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same bug in `2.5.0-alpha01`, `2.5.0-alpha02`, and `2.5.0-alpha03` but finally was able to get it to work in `2.5.0-alpha04`. 4th time is the charm!

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a navigation error. The problem is that the Tab is repeatedly clicked. The temporary solution is to return equally.

```kotlin
NavigationBarItem(
    icon = {
        Icon(painterResource(id = screen.icon), contentDescription = screen.route)
    },
    selected = currentRoute == screen.route,
    onClick = {

        if (currentRoute == screen.route) {
            return@NavigationBarItem
        }

        navController.navigate(screen.route) {
            popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                saveState = true
            }
            launchSingleTop = true
            restoreState = true
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: The default behavior of a bottom navigation bar is to refresh the current view if selected again. This workaround break this behavior but it's cleaner for sure.

Answer (score -1):

There is indeed a bug in 2.5.0-alpha03. Remitting to 2.5.0-alpha02 fixed the bug

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.0-alpha03'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.0-alpha02'
```

fixed it for me